# Putting all <link rel="stylesheet" or "import" to another html file

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Hello i want to know if is this possible and if it is how to make it I have some imports and some `stylesheet` links and script in my main `index.php` is it possible to put them to another file with name `import.html` and load just this file instead of bunch of other links?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking but put them in a new file called, links.html (or whatever), then do a `include 'links.html'` inside your `<head>`?

Comment: I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: And how concretely will it looks?

Comment: That is php by the way, so it has to be surrounded with <?php code ?> tags.

Comment: it looks no different as if the actual html in that included file is in the actual script.  You don't have enough code posted so it is tough to say.

Comment: oh ok so <?php include 'links.html' ?> this?

Comment: Yes, assuming you are dropping this in actual HTML.

Comment: Nice it is working thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it helped.  I added that as an answer, please mark correct if you don't mind when it allows it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing it like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <?php include head.html; ?>  
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The HTML in `head.html` contains your  info.  It will appear as if it is in the actual `index.php` script.

Edit:  As mentioned in an another answer, I am not sure of the benefit of this (other than cleaner clode maybe? keeping things modularized?), but since you asked how to do it, this is how.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do only really works if you are using some form of templating system.

Your current system sounds rather rudimentary, so as a result, you'll likely only be replacing a couple of `<link>` lines with an `<?php import('imports.html') ?>` line. It is doable, but I question the benefit here.

How many things are you importing that you feel you need to take this route? Can your stylesheets and javascript be merged into one file for each language?

Additionally, the general recommendation is for Javascript to be in the foot, just before the closing `</body>` tag, which would then require a second import statement to achieve what you're looking to do.

That said, you might want to broaden the scope of those imports into "head" and "foot" files, which hold not just the script imports, but the boilerplate head and foot HTML, so your content files only have a line of import on the top and bottom and need only be concerned with page-specific stuff. This gives you even less to copy and paste across pages.

If your project is more complex than what a simple include can provide, then you might want to look at a templating system, like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), which allows for more robust layout inheritance.